# Is it possible to add editable/movable horizontal line on Clustered Column Chart Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Want to add a **horizontal line** on the chart that can be **editable/movable** by the user.

See the orange line in below chart sample. Is it possible in **Power BI**? How can I achieve this?

[image: See Image]

Comment: Need like this https://jsfiddle.net/foa6fzy2

Answer (score 2):

For the standard set of visuals you can use a 'What if' measure and slicer combination to allow the user to set a line value.
You'll need to use the visual line and cluster column (or stacked column). Drag the items in as normal for the axis and columns, then select under the modelling tab 'New Parameter What if'

[image: What if screenshot]

Set your Min/Max values
This will create a new Parameter table' with the following in it (You can rename all the objects:

[image]

This will add a slicer to the page, the values will be passed to a measure that can now be plotted on the visual. Drag the 'Parameter Value' measure to the Line Values axis. For example slicer set at '600'

[image: Updated visual with slicer]

Move the slicer and it will update the line, for example slicer set at '1000'

[image]